# take last grep in a list of files

Tags: bash, grep

I have a list of files where I wan't the N lines following `something_cool` in a list of files So I do `grep -Hn -A N 'something_cool' *cool_file_discriminator*.cool_file_ending` but this gives me a list like:

- `file1` `something_cool` at line k
- line1
- line2

.

.

.

- line N
- `file1` `something_cool` at line g
- line1
- line2

.

.

.

- line N
- `file2` `something_cool` at line k
- line1
- line2

.

.

.

- line N

I would like only to have the last occurance of the match show up (tail, as far as I can tell, does not work, as it takes only 'fileK' and not all earlier files).

Thanks in advance

## Edit (expected output)

I would expect the last set of lines from every file to appear once in the final output:

- `file1` `something_cool`  at line g
- line1
- line2

.

.

.

- line N
- `file2` `something_cool`  at line g
- line1
- line2

.

.

.

- line N

Comment: Put your expected output in the question as well.

Comment: @AbhijitPritam did that thing ;-)

Comment: See: https://serverfault.com/questions/197123/getting-the-last-match-in-a-file-using-grep

Comment: thanks a lot the `-m 1` option was exactly what I needed @cmbuckley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified according to EdMorton comment (no loop over ls, quoted variable). If I understood correctly the question, this is doing the job but sorry for the bad formatting of my previous bash command...

You can do your `grep` on every file individually and `tail` the last N+1 lines of the result.
Integrated in a for loop:

```
for file in <your_forlder> ; do grep -Hn -A N 'something_cool' "$file" | tail -n N+1 ; done ;
```

---

As a comment: `grep -m 1` will stop after the first match and then will not print the last one. Depends on what you need...

Comment: I think you're correct on the comment, but as far as I can tell, it gives me the same output as your command, wich makes no sense to me.

Comment: This contains a few bugs and anti-patterns (e.g. parsing the output of ls, looping on the output of a command, calling a command uselessly, unquoted variables, etc.). I can't understand the OPs question due to it's bad formatting but whatever it is she's trying to do, this is not the way to do it.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm trying to grep a file, from bottom to the top, and taking the N lines (from top to bottom) after a match. Only including the first match in the output. Also I'm very much not a girl.

Comment: OK, post a new, well formatted question if you'd like help doing that the right way and don't be so quick to accept the first answer you get next time.